# Can't get a pause function to work with my javascript stopwatch

Tags: javascript

Can some one help me. I can't seem to get this stopwatch to pause and displayed the paused(stopped) time, and then reactivate when I hit start again.

I don't know how to stop the timer from counting up. Not sure if it's best practice to end the timer function, create a new function for current time, or to keep subtracting 1 from it using the setInterval?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var digit=-1.0;
var min=0;
var time;


function timer(){
        digit++;       

        if(digit>59){
                min++;
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=padTimer(min);
                digit=0;
        }
        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=padTimer(digit);  
}

function padTimer(x) {
        if (x<=9) { x = ("0"+x); }
        return x;
}  

function start(){
                time=setInterval(timer, 1000);
                timer();
}

function pause() {
}

function reset(){
            digit=-1.0;
            timerPay=0;              
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="start()">Click here to start the timer</a>
<a href="#" onclick="pause()">Click here to pause the timer</a>

<a href="#" onclick="reset()">Click here to reset the timer</a>

<div>
<span id="mins" >00</span>:<span id="secs">00</span><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`function pause() {
clearInterval(time);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearInterval(time)` to remove the interval.

http://jsfiddle.net/tQE5p/

Answer (score 1):

since the interval is happening in the time variable,so you should use `clearInterval(time)` in your pause function!

Answer (score 1):

No doubt that `clearInterval` is your answer, but you have a serious bug in your code: what if a user clicks on the start button a lot of times (clue: a lot of intervals are registered)?

I wrote a more reasonable `constructor function` for you. when a user clicks `start`, `timerStarted` changes to `true` and vice versa.
In addition, as it is a `constructor function`, there is no global variables (except the `Timer` function itself) and you can create as timers as you want. each timer should be created by the `new` reserved keyword.

```
function Timer (intervalSeconds) {
    this.__intervalSeconds = intervalSeconds;
    this.reset();
};

Timer.prototype.start = function () {
    if (!this.__timerStarted) {
        var self = this;

        this.__timerEventRegistered = setInterval(function() {
            self.timeElapsed += self.__intervalSeconds;
        }, this.__intervalSeconds);
    }
    this.timerStarted = true;
};

Timer.prototype.pause = function () {
    clearInterval(this.__timerEventRegistered);
    this._timerStarted = false;
}

Timer.prototype.reset = function () {
    this.pause();
    this.timeElapsed = 0;
}

// Timer creation example; the timer will be updated each 1000 milliseconds (= 1 second).
var timer = new Timer(1000);
```

You have an access to `timer.timeElapsed` so you can see the time and doing some manipulates.

**PLEASE NOTE:** as Javascript is a single-threaded, there is no guarantee that the timer will work perfectly. actually, it could be far away from this in some situations.